# Why does my else statement trigger all the time

Tags: python

I made a simple rock paper scissors game in python to learn. Everything is working except the last else statement. I simply want to check if none of the previous if statements are true then it prints out 'not a valid command' but for some reason it prints it out regardless what i type. Must be something very basic I'm missing but I just can't see it.

```
import random
while True:
    cpu_choice = random.randint(0, 2)
    cpu = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    print("Pick Rock,Paper or Scissors")
    choice = input("")
    if choice.capitalize() == "Paper":
        if cpu_choice == 2:
            print("You lose")
        elif cpu_choice == 1:
            print("Tied!")
        else:
            print("You won!")

    if choice.capitalize() == "Rock":
        if cpu_choice == 1:
            print("You lose")
        elif cpu_choice == 0:
            print("Tied!")
        else:
            print("You won!")

    if choice.capitalize() == "Scissors":
        if cpu_choice == 0:
            print("You lose")
        elif cpu_choice == 2:
            print("Tied!")
        else:
            print("You won!")

    if choice.capitalize() == "Exit":
        print("Exiting...")
        break

    else:
        print("Not a valid command")

    print("Computer picked: " + cpu[cpu_choice])
```

Comment: Those `if`s should be `elif`s.

Comment: The pattern is `if ... elif ... elif ... elif ... else`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. For debugging help in the future, you'll need to make a [mre]. This isn't a bad example, but there's a bunch of irrelevant details that distract from the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Your `else` statement will run whenever `choice.capitalize() == "Exit"` evaluates to False. You need to turn all your other `if` statements into `elif` statements to treat it all as one if/elif/else block.

```
if choice.capitalize() == "Paper":
    ...
elif choice.capitalize() == "Rock":
    ...
elif choice.capitalize() == "Scissors":
    ...
elif choice.capitalize() == "Exit":
    ...
else:
    print("Not a valid command")
```